# Handling query failures in react-router-relay

Tags: relayjs, react-router-relay

I am new to Relay and am working on a small project using `react-relay/classic` with `react-router-relay`. I am trying to decide the best way to implement simple error handling for the case where a *query* fails.

I am just looking for a "catch all" system which will allow me to tell the user that it looks like they're not online. Nothing more complex is required.

From the Relay [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-root-container.html#renderfailure), it looks like the regular relay way to do this would be with the `renderFailure` prop on `Relay.RootContainer`. However, as I am using `react-router-relay` I never create a `Relay.RootContainer` directly - it looks like these are created under-the-hood by `react-router-relay`.

I haven't been able to find anything in `react-router-relay` documentation about how to access the underlying `Relay.RootContainer` props, or on error handling. I have also had a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay) and nothing obvious jumps out.

So my question is: is there any way I catch query failures when using `react-router-relay`?